# how to login with hidden csrf-token in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csrf, autologin, csrf-token

i have one external website's login form link with below field, there are username, password and terms field visible and one hidden field that is _token (csrf-token). how to auto login of that external website on click of my current website's button click.

I tried many solution everytime i got response 419 Page Expired. My current website is on ASP.NET MVC 5 C#

```
<form id="login" class="login" target="_blank" method="post" action="https://test.com/login">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="qwewqewqewqewqewqewq">
        <input id="username" name="username" value="" />
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" />
        <input id="terms" type="checkbox" name="terms" checked />
        <button type="submit"></button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Any kind of help will be appreciable